# Algorithm to find # elements less than target in a sorted Matrix in O(n)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, matrix

Design an algorithm that outputs the number of entries in A that are smaller than or equal to x. Your algorithm should run in O(n) time.

For example in the array below if my target was '5' then I would return 2 b/c 1 and 3 are smaller.

```
[1, 3,  5]
[2, 6,  9]
[3, 6, 10]
```

I gave it a shot with the code below which is close to working and I think it's O(n) ... the problem I see is if I don't have the # in my array I am not sure if I am returning the right value?

```
def findLessX(m,n,x):
    i = 0
    j = n-1

    while (i < n and j >= 0):
        if i == n or j == n:
            print("n not found")
            return (i+1)*(j+1)-1


        if (m[i][j] == x):
            print(" n Found at ", i , " ", j)
            return (i+1)*(j+1)-1
        elif (m[i][j] > x):
            print(" Moving left one column")
            j = j - 1
        elif (m[i][j] < x):
            print(" Moving down one row")
            i = i + 1

    print(" n Element not found so return max")
    return (i)*(j+1)

# Driver code
x = 5
n = 3
m = [ [1, 3, 5],
      [2, 6, 9],
      [3, 6, 9]]
print("Count=", findLessX(m, n, x))
```

Inspect the Count and simple matrix above to see if soln works ~

Comment: How exactly is your matrix sorted?

There is no way to get the result of the example matrix in O(n). In the example there are 4 numbers smaller 5: 1, 2, 3 and 3. Just by iterating untill you find the largest number `< x` and then returning `i*j` you will not get the answer.

Comment: @RomCoo The numbers to the left  in a row are <= number to the right of them. The numbers above in a column are smaller than the numbers below them. You can assume all numbers are distinct but  let's say the matrix above is given you are going to have an issue. Eventually next part of question is to find the median of the matrix in nlogn time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both columns and rows are sorted ascending, then for any given border value some stairs line does exist. It divides matrix into two parts - higher (and equal) and lower than border value. That line always goes left and down (if traversal starts from top right corner).

```
[1, 3,  |5]
    ____|
[2,| 6,  9]
[3,| 6, 10]
```

So scan from top right corner, find starting cell for that line on the right or top edge, then follow the line, counting elements being left to it.

Complexity is linear, because line never turns back.

P.P.S. I hoped that you could write code with given clues

```
def countLessX(m,n,x):
    col = n-1
    count  = 0

    for row in range(n):
        while (col >= 0) and (m[row] [col] >= x):
            col = col - 1
        count = count + col + 1
    if col < 0:   #early stop for loop
        break
    return count

# Driver code
n = 3
m = [ [1, 3, 5],
      [2, 6, 9],
      [3, 6, 9]]
for x in range(11):
   print("x=", x, "Count=", countLessX(m, n, x))

x= 0 Count= 0
x= 1 Count= 0
x= 2 Count= 1
x= 3 Count= 2
x= 4 Count= 4
x= 5 Count= 4
x= 6 Count= 5
x= 7 Count= 7
x= 8 Count= 7
x= 9 Count= 7
x= 10 Count= 9
```

Comment: does this mean my code is okay or what is the advantage to your method (srry just wondering why start bottom left to right)?

Comment: I chosen direction randomly, there is no difference, start from the right top corner is OK. But your code is wrong - you should not return if border element is found with area of some rectangle. What rectangle?? You can see at my picture that you have to add lengths of all segments left to border path.

Comment: can you supplement some python code and I double check and close this issue out? Just want to confirm on some tests ... Agreed my code is wrong due to bug pointed in comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment your problem is not solveable in O(n) for most matrices. Some other thoughts:

- Why count j downwards?
- `i` and `j` can never become `n`

Here is a solution in O(n) that perhaps fullfills your needs.

Here is the adapted code:

```
def findLessX(m,n,x):
  i = 0
  j = 0

  while True:
    if i+1<n and m[i+1][j]<x:
      i=i+1
    elif j+1<n and m[i][j+1]<x:
      j=j+1
    else:
      print("n found at ", i+1 , " ", j+1, "or element not found so return max")
      return (i+1)*(j+1)
```

Comment: Ughhh this code isn't compling interesting index our of range on the if (m[i+1][j]<=x && i+1<n) ....  So I know that the top right value is a number (lets say 5)... if  our target is lets say 3 I can move to the left and get the count as 2 but the problem is I miss the 2  under the 1. Do you know why python won't let your code to compile ... trying a few things.

Comment: it's Compiling thanks! okay let me run some tests ... between you and MBo , I think that if your code passes I'll give you the answer but thanks both for trying ~ Not working will add basic driver code to question please make sure count is depicted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers suggested above will result in O(n^2).
In worst case, the algorithms will inspect all n^2 elements in the matrix.

Comment: This isn't an answer per se, but a comment for the other two answers.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I don't have enough reputation score to leave a comment :(